# MacBook air is messed up, can't erase the hard drive from recovery

Tags: macos, startup, recovery

Something happened when installing El Capitan and now I have only one partition in my hard drive with only 30 gigs of space when it's supposed to be 128. I can't seem to erase anything. Any advice?

Comment: Could be a broken hard drive.

Comment: Could you provide us the error message when you’re trying to format the drive?

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot in safe mode to fix any minor disk problem

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: I was planning to add something when I have something else than my phone to write